# UML and constraint and association/aggregation

Tags: associations, uml, constraints, aggregation

I would like to ask you about the following situation:

There is a class named A. It contains (aggregation) two classes (B and C), but they didn't inherited from the same base class. 
Is it possible to associate B and C to A and use a constraint with {or}, but with only one reference at the A's side? 
An other solution could be use of interface (Iface), so I can associate A with Iface, B and C can realise Iface. 
But the question is that can I use constraint for this? 
(as I found, associating B and C to A means that A will contain a reference for B and an other reference for C).

Thank you,

Ferenc

Comment: What level of class diagram are you dealing with? You mention that A 'will contain a reference' which implies you are generating code from this - if so, what do you want the type of the reference to B|C to be?

Comment: Hi Pete! I asked this because I think that if I associate B and C to A and B and C have no same base class then A will contain 2 properties/references/attributes and not only one. If this is true then I can't use constraint to simplify the diagram as I described, but I have to use an interface that implemented by B and C or I need to inherit B and C from a same base class like Eoin's diagram. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is whether you can model A having a single association to another object, which can be of type B or C.  Is that right?

In which case you don't need a constraint, just an association from A to a new class (call it "D") and then B and C would inherit from D, like this:

[image]

This does of course mean that you have to identify common characteristics of B and C to factor out into D to allow substitutability.  And A can only rely on those features of B and C.

If you need A to have regular associations to B or C and can't use inheritance then you need separate associations with an {or} constraint as you've correctly identified.

Comment: Hi Eoin! I'm sorry, maybe it was misunderstandable. Let see your example: there is a class names A. I want to associate class C and class B to class A and I want see only one field in class A for this. But class B and class C have no same base class. Can I show it with an association between A and B and between A and C and using a {or} constraint both of association?

Comment: Having only one field in A for a reference to two possible types doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  The way to do this in a programming language is to have a reference to the type Object (the base class of all other classes), then you can reference any object via that reference.  But, unless you cast the reference to a specific type (which is effectively working around the type system) you can't do anything specific with that object reference.

Comment: Can you explain in more concrete terms what you're trying to model and why you only want one reference?

Comment: Hello! This version with constraint is not my idea. I said that I have to apply an inheritence (as you showed to me) or an interface which realised by B and C and agregated by A. But I got that it's too complex and it's possible to show with constraint. I think it's not the same... I read the UML specification of OMG, but I didn't find any a rule for this situation...

Comment: You're right, using the {or} constraint and using inheritance are different.  One will result in a single (polymorphic) reference to an object, which can only be used as an instance of the shared base type that it references.  The other results in two references, one to ClassB and one to ClassC, with one or the other populated at any one time.  In this case, you can use all the features of ClassB or ClassC.  Neither is "right", both are valid, you just need to decide which one works for your situation.  It's a question of modelling judgement.